# Why isn't the black color of the id="header" not showing?

Tags: html, css

I have written this code,all the divs are working properly also the nav is. But the black color of the "header" does not seem to work. I have posted the whole code below.Please have a look at the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

body
{
    padding: 0;
}
#container
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:100%;
    height: 1500px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#header
{
    background-color: black;    
    margin: 0px;
}

#logo
{
    background-color: green;
}

#headTable
{
    float:right;
}

#logo
{
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 70px;
    float: left;
    width:150px;
    height:100px;
}

#headTable ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
}

#headTable ul li
{
    color: black;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 50px;
}

#nav
{
    clear: both;
    width:100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: purple;
}

#nav ul
{
    margin-left: 100px;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav ul li
{
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
}



</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo"> 
            <img src="plane.jpg" width="150" height="100">
        </div>
        <div id="headTable">
            <ul>
                <li>Google</li>
                <li>Google</li>
                <li>Google</li>
            </ul>   
         </div>
    </div>

        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li>Menu</li>
                <li>Blog</li>
                <li>Ins</li>
                <li>BBC</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
                <li>Others</li>
            </ul>       
         </div>

    <div id="content">   

        <div id="page">
            <p>This is a paragraph that should
            stay intact inside the id of Page.
            </p>    
        </div>

        <div id="top">
            <p>THis is a paragraph that should
            stay intact inside the id of top.
            </p>
        </div>

        <div id="low">
            <p>This is a paragraph that should
            stay intact inside the id of bottom.
            </p>    
        </div>

    </div>
</div>              

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: apply overflow: hidden; to your #header ID.

Comment: how does overflow work?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I created a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/JsA7y/.
So , of course I might have the same "problem" as you ;
the img src point nowhere (in the jsfiddle).
? Where does your img point to ?
? Is the img in the same directory as your html ?
=> Other wise , you will need to use the correct uri ;
such as , if the img is in  a directory at the same level as the html :

```
<img src="directory/plane.jpg" width="150" height="100">
```

...
Hope this helps.

Comment: The question isn't about a broken image in a jsFiddle (those happen all the time). It's about the parent not containing the floated children.

Comment: ? why the neg ? I updated the http://jsfiddle.net/JsA7y/2/ to point to an actual image & It NOw Works ! - O.P. FYI theree are acoouple of web-based picture _ holder - generators : http:// lorempixel.com/ ; http:// pipsum.com/ ; & my fav. http:// dummyimage.com/ ; because you can embed the img size.

Comment: I guess you're right ... If the other answeres are what the OP was looking for , I guess I did not understand the nature of the OP question. {My inexperience & exuberance is showing}

Answer (score 2):

Add `overflow:auto` to `#header`:

```
#header {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ChKfW/)**

Floating the content makes the parent act as if there's no content and it collapses. Adding the overflow rules restores the behavior you seek.

Answer (score 0):

Because `#header` in this context has no defined size because the only elements it contains have floats.

Three easy ways around this:

1. Explicitly define dimensions for `#header`.
2. Add `display:inline-block` to `#header`.
3. Use a clearfix after the two floated elements in `#header`. This is done most commonly by using `<div style="clear:both;"><!-- --></div>`

Answer (score -1):

you must put some "Height" to you #header tag in CSS.  Good Luck !